# Im trying to extract data from a URL in Python and geeting this error when trying to find the most common data source

Tags: python, dataframe

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd

# Read the data from the Wikipedia page into a Pandas DataFrame
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population"
df = pd.read_html(url, attrs={"class": "wikitable"})[0]

# Visualize the DataFrame
print(df)

# Print the number of records in the DataFrame
print(f"There are {len(df)} records in the DataFrame.")


# Find the most common data source
most_common_source = df["Source"].value_counts().index[0]

print(f"The most common data source is {most_common_source}.")
```

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3360             try:
> -> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3362             except KeyError as err:
>
> 8 frames pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'Source'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in
> get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    3361                 return
> self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)    3362             except KeyError
> as err:
> -> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err    3364     3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:
>
> KeyError: 'Source'

Comment: When you printed the dataframe, did you see a column called `"Source"`?

Answer (score 0):

The table you are trying to extract from does not have a column named *Source*. Maybe you meant something like this:

```
most_common_source = \
    df["Source (official or from the\xa0United Nations)"].value_counts().index[0]
```

You can always print your columns with `list(df.columns)`.